# How do I create a rectangle from two points?

Tags: c++, .net, rectangles, system.drawing

I have two points, let's say the upper left and lower right corner of a rectangle, in C++ .Net. How do I create a System.Drawing.Rectangle structure from these two points in .net? This should be simple, am I missing something? 
The Rectangle constructor only works with Point and Size given, and by giving separate integer values, which I don't take into count here. It does not work by giving two points.
A Size strucure also can not be created from two points in a simple way. Subtracting one point from another is not defined, which should give a Size, and I see no other function that does that.
So I have to write the functions for that by myself? It should just be there.

Comment: If you have the top-left and bottom-right corners, you have the dimensions of the rectangle. Get the x and y coords of each point (you may need to use getters), and subtract them. Also please tag your language and say what graphics library you're using.

Comment: Of course I could do this manually, but I need it quite often. It should just be there, System.Drawing.Rectangle in .Net is the only rectangle implementation that I know that does not seem to have this.
Well, I also better use the double number format so I am just writing my own classes. Can share if anyone is interested.

Comment: Just make a function, then use the function. A pseudo-constructor solves that problem.

Comment: Emil can you point a link to a example where you have a rectangle that takes in two points to make a rectangle? because I have never seen a rectangle example that does do that (I have seen subtracting two points making a rectangle, but that could go either way, it depends on if you treat your points as points or as 2d vectors)

Comment: @ScottChamerlain: The System.Windows.Rect structure can be constructed either from two points or from point and size:<br>
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect(v=vs.110).aspx<br>

And in the MFC RECT structure you directly put the coordinates of the corner points.<br>

The Delphi TRect type could also use two points for construction:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Types.TRect

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a static method that converts your two points in to a size then have it call the constructor of rectangle that takes in a point and a size.

This answer is in C# syntax but you should easily be able to convert it to C++/cli syntax.

```
public static Rectangle GetRectangle(Point topLeft, Point bottomRight)
{
    var size = new Size(topLeft.X-bottomRight.X, topLeft.Y-bottomRight.Y);
    return new Rectangle(topLeft, size);
}
```

**Addition: the original answer above will lead to a negative size**
:

```
Point topLeft = new Point(0, 0);
Point bottomRight = new Point(100, 200);
Rectangle rect = GetRectangle(topLeft, bottomRight);
```

The rectangle will have a Width of `-100`; So it should be:

```
var size = new Size(bottomRight.X, bottomRight.Y-topLeft.Y);
```

Or even better: if you don't want to bother about which of the two points is at TopLeft:

```
public static Rectangle GetRectangle(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    int left = Math.Min(p1.X, p2.X);
    int right = Math.Max(p1.X, p2.X);
    int top = Math.Min(p1.Y., p2.Y);
    int bottom = Math.Max(p1.Y, p2.Y);
    int width = right - left;
    int height = bottom - top;
    return new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);
}
```

I did this in baby steps to make things easy to understand. Of course this can be optimized.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is so simple, I should have seen this right away.